# GNUplot: Set x axis to array values

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I'm using GNUplot in c++ where I have an array of x-values of size N and for each value I find the corresponding y-value and store them in an array called y. When I do: `plot y` (actual c++ line: `gp << "plot " << gp.file1d(y) << endl;`), the shape of the graph is correct but the x axis goes from 0 to N but I want it to go from the lowest value to the highest value of x. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When plotting an array, the index is used as x and the actual value is used as y. You have to find a way to put your x and y values into one 2D object, e.g. as a data block, where the first column is your x and the second one is y. Or provide two arrays `xvals` and `yvals` and then call `plot xvals u 1:(yvals[$0+1])`. However, I am not familiar with c++ and can't help with the actual syntax.

Comment: Thank you! Like you said I defined a new array with the x and y values as you said and passed that instead and now it works like I want to.